# how can I set permission for users with multiple repositories each, on svn?

Tags: svn, debian

I am using svn and I have this doubt, I install svn server (normal way) and I created the repo with `svnadmin create project` right now im using linux users to access them with the following protocol

```
svn+ssh://user@serverip/project
```

it works fine if I want only one user with one project, if not, i have to create groups, assign the users to the group and give it permission to the folder with a `chmod` manually

I checked modifying authz and passwd files (on the /config folder) but nothing.

Any idea what would be the right way to set the repositories, users and permissions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must read this :

http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Trac_with_Apache2_SVN_and_multiple_Repositories

Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

When doing svn+ssh authentication where each user has their own user account on the server, and you want them all to have read/write access then you will need to:

- Create a group that the users can belong to (svn-groupname)
- chmod -R 770 /var/svn/reponame
- chmod -R g+s /var/svn/reponame
- chgrp -R svn-groupname /var/svn/reponame

I strongly suggest that you formalize this by:

- Naming your repositories in a consistent manner.  Such has having all the repositories where the users are part of the same group have a consistent prefix.  That lets you apply permissions using wildcards.
- Create a /usr/local/sbin shell script (svn_set_repository_permissions.sh) to do the permission setting.  This lets you just run a single script later if the permissions get messed up or you add new repositories.
- Deciding whether you want to use 700 (user-only), 750 (user write, group read), 770 (user and group write), or some other permission set.

If you are doing both svn+ssh authentication plus http authentication, then you'll have to open up the permissions a lot more and use the SVN authorization files instead to restrict users.